# Query sum of conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT a13.MesAño MesAño,
       sum(a11.Cantidad) WJXBFS1
FROM [Histórico Lin_Factura Venta] a11
JOIN Producto a12 ON (a11.Nº = a12.Nº)
JOIN LU_Dia2 a13 ON (a11.[Fecha Registro] = a13.[Fecha Registro])
WHERE a11.[Fecha Registro] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 120)
  AND a12.Familia IN ('13         ')
  AND ( a11.Coleccion IN ('JL  ',
                          'G    ') -->>>> 1180
  OR a11.[Cod Grupo producto] IN ('          ',
                                  'OPORTUN   ',
                                  '2013  ',
                                  '20   ',
                                  'JUN12',
                                  'NEW2012   ') --> 6653
 )
GROUP BY a13.MesAño
ORDER BY a13.MesAño
```

========================================

sum to the first condition in January 1180 and the second 6653, why do they not add up to 7833?

Comment: Because there are some rows that satisfy both `or` conditions? If you sum individually you will add some values twice.

Comment: as would be the query to add both conditions?

Comment: Almost certainly you do not want to sum some values twice. You need to explain what you want to do and show table definition, sample data and expected result.

Comment: Can you please post the query result that you are getting right now?

Comment: 1 6653.00000
2 4556.00000
3 3469.00000
4 5410.00000
5 2630.00000
6 81.00000

Comment: month 1 , month 2.. year 2013, instead of 6653 would have to be 7833 (6653 +1180). 1180 is the condition a11.Coleccion in ('JL', 'G') - 1180 >>>>

Comment: a11.[Cod Grupo producto] in ('          ', 'OPORTUN   ', '2013  ', '20   ', 'JUN12', 'NEW2012   ') --> 6653

Comment: Well, that means that you data does not meet the condition `a11.[Fecha Registro] >=  CONVERT(datetime, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 120) and a12.Familia in ('13         ') and a11.Coleccion in ('JL  ', 'G    ') and a13.MesAño = 1`. You say `a11.Coleccion in ('JL', 'G')` alone totals 1180, but does not return that total when used together with the other conditions. Take a close look at your data.

Comment: Some more effort on picking a suitable title for your question and explaining what's happening would be appreciated (there's an edit link below your question). Tags belong in tags, not in the title (so you shouldn't have `SQL Server` there). And practically every SQL related question involves a `query`. Unfortunately, you've done a poor job with the rest of the question, so I can't even think of a suitable title to replace it with myself.

Comment: Thanks Jose, yes, it's what he says. for the month of January (1), 6653 appearing when they should appear (6653 +1180) = 7833. I have reviewed the data and can not find the reason. If you just run the query with the first condition a11.Coleccion in ('JL', 'G') - >>>> 1180 if there is either (1180) or the second (6653) a11. [Cod Product Group] in ('', 'opportun', '2013 ', '20', 'JUN12', 'NEW2012') -> 6653, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some rows match both conditions? If so, then the result won't count those rows twice.

Since you didn't provide a schema and example data, it's really hard to do more than guess. But that's the first answer that comes to mind.

Comment: as would be the query to add both conditions? 1180 para   a11.Coleccion in ('JL  ', 'G    ') y  a11.[Cod Grupo producto] in ('          ', 'OPORTUN   ', '2013  ', '20   ', 'JUN12', 'NEW2012   ') --> 6653

Comment: 1 6653.00000 no..  1    7833 (sum of both)